# Ruby: Using net-ssh inside Timeout.timeout() doesn't close the ssh connection on timout

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

The program I'm making has multiple options of logging in. When checking an option, we give in the username and password and check if a connection is established. If it's not, the **SSH** will get stuck on `Invalid password` and it will ask for another password.

The **SSH** is inside `Timeout.timeout(6)`, so when this happens, it gives an exception and tries another username/password or connects over **telnet**.

This works as long as the function is only called once in a while. Since the program can be used by multiple users, the **SSH** will start refusing connections because the **SSH** connections inside the timeout function only close after 60 seconds. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `Timeout.timeout` throws/raises `Timeout::Error`, so catch/rescue it and close your SSH connection in the rescue handler.